# How to install TensorFlow without default dataset?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

The current release version of the TensorFlow package is as large as **459.2MB**.

I believe **the default dataset** might take quite a large space in the 459.2MB. So, how can I only download the TensorFlow module, without the default datasets? I won't be using those datasets in any way in the future.

Comment: What do you mean "the default dataset"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `pip` package `tensorflow` now contains GPU-support, which is much larger than the non-GPU package. To install the package without GPU support, use `pip install tensorflow-cpu`. Datasets are downloaded when you want to use them, so they do not count towards the package size.